Zoom in ChartJS is not centered in the mouse position
I'm having trouble with the zoom using ChartJS. I'm using a canvas with a candle chart to display the stock price and other two canvas to display bars for the volume.
The problem is that when zooming, it does not zoom where I have the cursor. It moves the X axis and it ends up in a different position. I attach a gif below:
https://gifyu.com/image/SJPgi
This is the code I use to populate the data into the candle chart
const customPlugins = [
    crosshairPlugin,
    smaPlugin,
    emaPlugin,
    fixedWidthYAxisPlugin,
    chartMaxCandleWidthPlugin,
    createPanPlugin,
    createZoomPlugin,
];

candleChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: stock.Name,
            data: items,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                time: {
                    unit: intradayUnit,
                },
                grid: {
                    display: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    stepSize: intradayStepSize,
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90,
                    padding: 10,
                    color: 'transparent'
                },
                offset: false,
                min: minDate,
                max: new Date()
            },
            y: {
                position: 'right',
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Price'
                }
            }
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            zoomPlugin: {},
            sync: { targets: [] },
            sma: {
                enabled: $scope.FilteringOptions.Filters.ShowSMA,
                itemProperty: 'c',
                locked: $scope.FilteringOptions.Filters.SMALocked,
            },
            ema: {
                enabled: $scope.FilteringOptions.Filters.ShowEMA,
                itemProperty: 'c',
                locked: $scope.FilteringOptions.Filters.SMALocked,
            },
            fixedWidthYAxis: true,
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                bottom: -30
            }
        },
        onHover: function (event, elements) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.SelectChartElement(elements);
            });

            const rect = event.chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            candleChart.mouseX = event.native.clientX - rect.left;
            candleChart.mouseY = event.native.clientY - rect.top;
            candleChart.mouseActive = true;
            candleChart.update();
        }
    },
    plugins: customPlugins
});

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    candleChart.mouseActive = false;
    candleChart.update();
});

return candleChart;

This is the code for the Zoom (generated with chatGPT, tried a lot of prompts but none worked, always the same code):
const createZoomPlugin = {
    id: 'zoomPlugin',
    afterInit: (chart) => {
        const canvas = chart.canvas;

        chart.zoomState = {
            zoomFactor: 1.15,
            minZoomRange: 1000 * 60 * 5,
            maxZoomRange: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 60, 
        };

        canvas.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const xScale = chart.scales.x;
            if (!xScale) return;

            const mouseX = event.offsetX;
            const mouseValue = xScale.getValueForPixel(mouseX);

            const currentMin = xScale.min;
            const currentMax = xScale.max;
            const currentRange = currentMax - currentMin;

            const zoomFactor = event.deltaY > 0 ? chart.zoomState.zoomFactor : 1 / chart.zoomState.zoomFactor;
            const newRange = currentRange * zoomFactor;

            if (newRange > chart.zoomState.maxZoomRange || newRange < chart.zoomState.minZoomRange) {
                return;
            }

            const rangeProportion = (mouseValue - currentMin) / currentRange;
            const correctedMouseValue = Math.round(mouseValue);
            const newMin = correctedMouseValue - rangeProportion * newRange;
            const newMax = newMin + newRange;

            xScale.options.min = newMin;
            xScale.options.max = newMax;

            chart.update('none');

            if (chart.config.options.plugins.sync) {
                chart.config.options.plugins.sync.targets.forEach((targetChart) => {
                    const targetXScale = targetChart.scales.x;
                    if (!targetXScale) return;

                    targetXScale.options.min = xScale.options.min;
                    targetXScale.options.max = xScale.options.max;

                    targetChart.update('none');
                });
            }
        });


    },
};


Using "time" instead of "timeseries" is making it work correctly. But the problem is the holes in the chart, thats why we use timeseries.
What I want to achieve is that when zooming in/out, it it always centered in the mouse position, not moving the candles to right/left.
Scripts I'm using:
chartJS 4.4.5
luxon 3.5.0
chartjs-adapter-luxon v1.3.1
hammer 2.0.7
thanks
I tried different solutions provided by chatGPT for the zoom function but none worked.
I expect it to zoom centered in the mouse position.
I actually is zooming but moving the chart X axis to the side and the cursor ends up in a different position.
